# Mapping column exception Entity Framework MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 and EF 6.1.3 trying to implement a generic controller that manage a generic entity.
Here is the controller

**TemplateController.cs**

```cs
public class TemplateController<TEntity> : Controller where TEntity : TemplateEntity
{

    protected DbContext db;

    public TemplateController()
    {
    }

    public TemplateController(DbContext _db)
    {
        db = _db;
    }

    public ActionResult Detail(int? id) 
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }


        if (id != null)
        {
            //this works
            //TEntity tEntityDb = db.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);

            //this doesn't work
            TEntity tEntityDb = db.Set<TEntity>().Where(t => t.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();


            if (tEntityDb == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View("Detail", tEntityDb);
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
// and so on
}
```

This is the generic entity TemplateEntity

**TemplateEntity.cs**

```cs
public class TemplateEntity
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TemplateEntity()
    {}

}
```

Then in my model every entity class derive from TemplateEntity. Now I have a specific entity called task_h like this

**Task_hExt.cs**

```cs
public partial class task_h : TemplateEntity
{

    [Column("id_task")]
    public new int Id
    {
        get { return id_task; }
        set
        {
            Id = id_task;
        }

    }

}
```

**task_h.cs**

```cs
public partial class task_h : TemplateEntity
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]

    public task_h()
    {
        this.task_d = new HashSet<task_d>();
        this.Id = id_task;
    }

    public int id_task { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }
    // other properties
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<task_d> task_d { get; set; }
}
```

Basically task_h.cs is generated by scaffolding database first.

The specific controller just inherit from TemplateController

**task_hController.cs**

```cs
public class task_hController : TemplateController<task_h>
{

    public task_hController()
    {
        this.db = new DBEntities(); 
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The problem is in this line

```cs
TEntity tEntityDb = db.Set<TEntity>().Where(t => t.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

That causes a System.NotSupportedException with message

> The specified type member 'Id' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

In task_h table on db doesn't exist  Id column but id_task column.  As you can see I've tried column attribute [Column("id_task")] in Task_hExt.cs but without success. I've tried also column attribute from System.Data.Linq.Mapping but this does't work. Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Shadowing base class properties is not a good idea in general, and especially with EF entity models.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you Ivan, what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: Code first or edmx?

Comment: The database already exists so edmx

Comment: I know how to make it with code first approach (which btw does not exclude existing database scenario - the name is bit misleading). But edmx is not my area of knowledge, hope someone else could help you. Good luck.